# ASP.NET AJAX Calendar extender date format

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3"/>
<asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="TextBox3_CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="TextBox3" 
                        Enabled="True" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" />
```

output calendar Format : **2/1/2010**
I need : **01.02.2010**

like here : [ajax calendar](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

how to setup this format ?..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the Format property.  Try `Format="dd.MM.yyyy"`.

Answer (score 1):

it's funny how this sounds but your question and the post helped me. I have a calendar extender in my markup and the format attribute was set to "dd/mm/yyyy". However, whenever I ran the app, the textbox doesn't change for the month part ONLY whenever i select a date.
I was thinking it was because I had it in an update panel but this was the solution: I used:

"dd/MM/yyyy" so that was it. "MM" enabled the month change whenever the date selection was changed. So thanks for the clue!

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple for you just go  in your code of calander extender and write their Format="dd.MM.yyyy"
i think this will resolve your problem...........

Comment: This is pretty much the exact answer that has already been accepted for this question.  If you're going to jump on a question that is 3+ years old, and still find that the existing answers are inadequate, please try to improve them somehow, instead of just repeating them.